# Is there a way to detect in javascript that the Backspace is long pressed in ios/android?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a web application built in Vue.js. I can only detect if the Backspace is long pressed using `keydown` on desktop's keyboard (specifically Windows PC). In desktop, the event is fired many times as long as you keep holding the Backspace key. But in mobile, it seems that it only fired once even if you hold the Backspace key longer.

What I'm trying to achieve is that, when I'm on the last field and clear the text, if all text are cleared, then closest previous field will be focused until all text are cleared and the cursor will point on the first field.

I already managed to sort the desktop, the only problem I have is on the mobile(android/ios).

[image]

HTML:

```
<input 
    @keydown="onKeydown(key, $event)"
    @paste="onPasteEvent(key, $event)"
    @keyup="onKeyup(key, $event)"
    @click="onInputClick(key, $event)"
    type="text" 
    :name="'input' + key"
    v-model="code[key]"
    :maxlength="(key === 0 ? 6 : 5)"
>
```

Keydown handler:

```
 onKeydown(key, event) {
        let input = document.querySelector('input[name="input'+ key +'"]');

        switch (event.key) {
            case 'Backspace':
                // If not in first field and no text before the cursor 
                // position; focus the previous field.
                if (key > 0 && !this.getPrevWord(input)) {
                    this.moveCursorLeft(key);
                }
                break;

            case 'Delete':
                // If not in last field and no text after the cursor position;
                // focus the next field.
                if (key < (this.inputs - 1) && !this.getNextWord(input)) {
                    this.moveCursorRight(key);
                }
                break;
        }
 },
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @AndrewL64, I updated the questions above to include some relevant code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the code of your `onkeyUp` event.

Comment: For js, you should probably check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

Comment: The behavior you're looking for is called "long press" on mobile. That will help you with the googling. :) I found several long press directives just trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
onKeydown(key, event) {
        let input = document.querySelector('input[name="input'+ key +'"]');

        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 8:

                // If not in first field and no text before the cursor position; focus the previous field
                if (key > 0 && !this.getPrevWord(input)) {
                    this.moveCursorLeft(key);
                }
                break;

            case 46:
                // If not in last field and no text after the cursor position; focus the next field
                if (key < (this.inputs - 1) && !this.getNextWord(input)) {
                    this.moveCursorRight(key);
                }
                break;
        }
 },
```

Comment: The use of keyCode events is deprecated and may not be supported in new browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode